# H2 DB cross join not executing

Tags: java, sql, h2

I'm using H2-1.4.191.jar DB and have this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT A.COL AS AC_1, B.COL AS BC_1 FROM A, B WHERE AC_1 = 'someconst') CROSS JOIN (SELECT A.COL AS AC_2, B.COL AS BC_2 FROM A, B WHERE AC_2 = 'another_const')) WHERE BC_1 <> BC_2 LIMIT 1
```

H2DB is placed in memory and is embedded DB in my Java App. When I try to execute SQL I get following exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement " SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT A.COL AS AC_1, B.COL AS BC_1 FROM A, B WHERE AC_1 = 'some_const') CROSS[*] JOIN (SELECT A.COL AS AC_2, B.COL AS BC_2 FROM A, B WHERE AC_2 = 'some_another_const')) WHERE BC_1 <> BC_2 LIMIT 1"; expected "UNION, MINUS, EXCEPT, INTERSECT, ORDER, OFFSET, FETCH, LIMIT, FOR, )";
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:535)
at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3170)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1170)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:291)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73)
at generation.db.QueryMaker.exec(QueryMaker.java:139)
```

In SQLite all works fine.
What should I do to make it work in H2?

Answer (score 0):

This query without outer brackets works correctly:

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.COL AS AC_1, B.COL AS BC_1 FROM A, B WHERE AC_1 = 'someconst') CROSS JOIN (SELECT A.COL AS AC_2, B.COL AS BC_2 FROM A, B WHERE AC_2 = 'another_const') WHERE BC_1 <> BC_2 LIMIT 1
```